# How to get a Custom QCompleter to work with a custom item delegate?

Tags: python, pyside2, qlineedit, qstyleditemdelegate, qcompleter

I have a custom qcompleter (to match any part of the string) and a custom QStyledItemDelegate (to show different formatting on the drop down options returned by the qcompleter) applied to a QLineEdit, and they both work individually however the QStyledItemDelegate doesn't work when I apply them both.

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLineEdit, QCompleter, QStyledItemDelegate
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QSortFilterProxyModel, QStringListModel
from PySide2.QtGui import QColor, QPalette
```

Qcompleter Item delegate:

```
class CompleterItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(CompleterItemDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.backgroundBrush = QColor("red")
        option.palette.setBrush(QPalette.Text, QColor("blue"))
        option.displayAlignment = Qt.AlignCenter
```

Custom QCompleter:

```
class CustomQCompleter(QCompleter):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomQCompleter, self).__init__(parent)
        self.local_completion_prefix = ""
        self.source_model = None

    def setModel(self, model):
        self.source_model = model
        super(CustomQCompleter, self).setModel(self.source_model)

    def updateModel(self):
        local_completion_prefix = self.local_completion_prefix
        class InnerProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
            def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):
                index0 = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent)
                searchStr = local_completion_prefix.lower()
                searchStr_list = searchStr.split()
                modelStr = self.sourceModel().data(index0,Qt.DisplayRole).lower()
                for string in searchStr_list:
                    if not string in modelStr:
                        return False
                return True

        proxy_model = InnerProxyModel()
        proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.source_model)
        super(CustomQCompleter, self).setModel(proxy_model)

    def splitPath(self, path):
        self.local_completion_prefix = str(path)
        self.updateModel()
        return ""
```

Main:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        model = QStringListModel()
        model.setStringList(['Tom', 'Tommy Stevens', 'Steven'])

        # ITEM DELEGATE ONLY - WORKS
        # completer = QCompleter()
        # completer.setModel(model)
        # delegate = CompleterDelegate()
        # completer.popup().setItemDelegate(delegate)

        # QCOMPLETER DELEGATE ONLY - WORKS
        # completer = CustomQCompleter(self)
        # completer.setModel(model)

        # ITEM DELEGATE AND QCOMPLETER DELEGATE - ITEM DELEGATE DOESNT WORK
        completer = CustomQCompleter(self)
        completer.setModel(model)
        delegate = CompleterItemDelegate()
        completer.popup().setItemDelegate(delegate)

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit.setCompleter(completer)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app  = QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = MainWindow()
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

1. Is there a way to make this code work?
2. Is there a better way to achieve both choosing the completion rules for the qcompleter and formatting the popup results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the delegate on the popup won't work if the model is set afterwards, since [`setModel()`](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/util/qcompleter.cpp#n1099) also calls [`setPopup()`](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/util/qcompleter.cpp#n1237), which in turn sets a [new item delegate](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/util/qcompleter.cpp#n1268).

So, you either:

- ensure that you set the delegate *after* setting the model on the completer;
- subclass the completer and override `setModel()`, by calling the base implementation and *then* restore the delegate, or `complete()` by restoring the delegate *before* the base implementation call; note that this won't work in your case because you called the base implementation in `updateModel()` which will clearly ignore the override;

Comment: Am I not setting the delegate after the model on the completer when I first call completer.setModel(model) and then completer.popup().setItemDelegate(delegate)?

Comment: Yes, you are, whenever splitPath (and then updateModel) is called.

Answer (score 0):

Moving

```
delegate = CompleterItemDelegate()
self.popup().setItemDelegate(delegate)
```

into the CustomQCompleter updateModel function solves the problem as pointed out by musicamante.

Comment: Please do not create answers that do not add anything new to existing ones, especially if they are already accepted: accepting an answer, if it works for you, is good enough. If you need to add clarifications about how you actually did it, just write that in a comment to the accepted answer.